# Ubuntu 10.04 has broken google desktop ctrl ctrl search bar feature

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-10.04, google-desktop-search

Before I upgraded to ubuntu 10.04, when I pressed Ctrl twice, a search bar popped up that allowed me to google desktop search my system. This no longer works and I miss that feature. Can I get it back, somehow?

A complete uninstall/restart/reinstall has not fixed this issue.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04, using gnome, having downloaded google desktop from the google linux repositories...

Comment: It looks like [you are not the only one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1442629), this must be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stopped working in Debian testing a while back. I opened Google Desktop Preferences and set the hotkey to Ctrl-F1.

Answer (score 1):

There are some workarounds (via http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1442629)

> Keep the Ctrl_L pressed for one second, in other words, here is the sequence I found:
>
> 1. List item
> 2. Press and hold Ctrl_L
> 3. hold Ctrl_L for one second.
>
> to make it disappear do the same thing... Also you can get the same results if you apply 
>   the same pattern while replacing _L with _R.
>
> Also I found another way that might be
>   simpler:
>
> 1. Press and hold Ctrl_L
> 2. DOUBLE Press and release Ctrl_R

Comment: The double press of the second key thing is my favourite workaround