# Making evince the default application for embedding PDFs in firefox in ubuntu

Tags: firefox, pdf, plugins, ubuntu-10.04, evince

While I'm on the subject of complaining about things that upgrading to ubuntu 10.04 broke (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/137528/ubuntu-10-04-has-broken-google-desktop-ctrl-ctrl-search-bar-feature)), another problem that happened on moving from 9.04 to 9.10 (I think) is this:

Firefox used to open embedded pdf files with evince and that was fine. Now it opens them with okular, which I don't like for several reasons. (Pg Up, Pg Dn keys don't work. I don't like the KDE save file dialogue box, because I'm used to gnome. )

So my question is: how do I change which program is used to embed PDFs in firefox in ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this thread: [HOWTO: Embed PDFs with Evince in Mozilla/Firefox](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=25685)

Comment: Awesome. Though I still don't understand WHY they made the decision to switch from evince to okular...

Comment: AARG. I just upgraded to 10.10 and it CHANGED BACK TO OKULAR. _why_!?